# Keep ajax loader in sight in a page with much content

Tags: html, css, ajax

I have this `div` that functions as the `AJAX` loader 'image'. It's pure css.
The problem I'm having is, the page has a lot of content and if you are somewhere down on the page, you won't see the loader because it's displayed somewhere at the top of the page (out of sight).

What do I need to change:

```
<div id="floatingBarsG" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; padding: 2px; z-index: 99999">
    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_01">
    </div>
    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_02">
    </div>
    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_03">
    </div>
    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_04">
    </div>
    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_05">
    </div>
    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_06">
    </div>
    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_07">
    </div>
    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_08">
    </div>
</div>
```

Tried all kinds of `margin` options, but nothing worked.

Comment: Please consider to make a fiddle (http://fiddle.net) to explain your problem. However have you looked into CSS-property position: fixed?

Comment: There's not much information on the style of your page but could you not put the loader in a footer with position: fixed so its always visible at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @ScottAlexander, the loader should be visible no matter where the user's scrollbar is. Also, I have more than just 1 AJAX call triggered on different 'points' (top/middle/bottom/and anything in between) on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#floatingBarsG
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Where will this display the loader?

Comment: In the middle of the page

Answer (score 1):

Here, your loader won't be at the center of the div. see:

```
#floatingBarsG {
    width:30px;
    height:16px;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-8px; */half of your loader height*/
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-15px; */half of your loader width*/
    */this will help you that the loader be at the center of your div and it is fixed there.*/
}
```